# How do I append static data to the END of a dynamically generated url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url, redirect

We are generating a dynamic url from the data entered into a form.  We are currently able to append this dynamic form data into the url, but need to include static data at the END of the dynamic data.

Here is the last part of the jQuery that appends the data:

```
 var inputs = $('#form1').find('input[type=text]').not('#url');
 var str = "http://yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?"
 var str2 = "&promoid=5030385&option1=999"
 inputs.each(
     function (i, item) {
         str += encodeURIComponent(item.name) + 
             "=" + 
             encodeURIComponent(item.value) + 
             "&";
     });

$('http://yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?').val(str+str2);

 });
```

The end result from what we get:
`http://yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?address=1290 atlantis ave&zip=80026`

And this is what we are trying to achieve:
`http://yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?address=1290 atlantis ave&zip=80026&promoid=5030385&option1=999`

The last bit (`promoid=5030385&option1=999`) will be constant for every form entry.

****EDIT****

I solved it by putting the static data as a hidden field in the html:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="promoid" value="5030385" id="promoid"/>
```

Thank you all for your comments and help!

Comment: Why are you using the `val` function?

Comment: It was recommended by someone else on StackOverflow to append form data to a url

Comment: I think there is another issue in your code. Can you post more code or a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var inputs = $('#form1').find('input[type=text]').not('#url');
  var str = "http://yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?"
  var str2 = "&amp;promoid=5030385&option1=999"

   inputs.each(function (i, item) {
   str += encodeURIComponent(item.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(item.value) + "&";
 });
   str = str+str2;
});
```

Comment: That sounded like it would work!  But then this was the result we got when we tried it:
yoururlhere.com/dispatch.aspx?address=4350+SW+Galewood+Street&apt=103&zip=97035